# SeachView does not use full width

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to make my SearchView full width something like Whatsapp. This is my result.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1a4Z1.jpg)
And this is my code

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="?searchAppBarButton"
    android:title="@string/buscar"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView" />
```

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.agregar_servicio_menu, menu);
    MenuItem myActionMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    searchView = (SearchView) myActionMenuItem.getActionView();
    searchView.clearFocus();
    searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    searchView.setQueryHint(getString(R.string.buscar_empresa));
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
```

and style

```
<style name="SearchViewMy" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.SearchView">
    <item name="searchHintIcon">@null</item>
    <item name="android:maxWidth">1000dp</item>
</style>
```

this is my wanted result for the widht of the SearchView

[Example2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijePC.jpg)

Comment: What is the current state of your SearchView? is it only a search icon?

Comment: It is an item from the menu above inside a toolbar filling it with onCreateOptionsMenu

Comment: You can find your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/62044968/12966304

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this library for creating search view like whatsapp "com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.4.0"

Link of this library [MaterialSearchView](https://github.com/MiguelCatalan/MaterialSearchView)